# QGIS 2.18.15 crashes when printing to pdf from Mac?

Tags: qgis, pdf, mac

I'm a beginner in QGIS.

I've tried printing a vector project (not too large) to pdf but the program crashes every time. Here is some of the information provided by the crash report generated by my Mac:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000600081c2036d
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]
```

I wasn't able to find an answer that seems to apply to my issue in the previous questions.

Comment: What were the previous questions that you examined?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53639/qgis-not-printing-to-pdf?rq=1

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32338/qgis-crashes-when-writing-to-pdf?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I was able to work around the issue by printing to Adobe pdf from the Composer tab  > Print to pdf.

Comment: Great! So please accept your own answer